# The intention behind the sub-mulipcative condition of matrix norms

Tags: functional-analysis

I noticed that the definition of 'matrix norm' includes an extra sub-multiplicative condition (apart from the definition of 'norm'), $$\lVert AB \lVert \leq \lVert A \lVert\lVert B \lVert,~~~~~~~~(*)$$ to make sense the continuity of matrix mulitiplication relative to the topological vector space induced by the same. But the definition of operator norm $\lVert T \lVert$, where $T$ is a linear operator from a normed linear space $(X,\lVert \cdot \lVert_X)$ to the normed linear space $(Y,\lVert \cdot \lVert_Y)$, via $$\lVert T \lVert=\inf\{\alpha>0~:~\lVert Tx \lVert_Y \leq \alpha \lVert x \lVert_X,~\text{for all}~x \in X\},$$
immediately allows the result $\lVert Tx \lVert_Y \leq  \lVert T \lVert\lVert x \lVert_X$, for all $x \in X$. Consequently, for the composition $T_1T_2$, we have $$\lVert T_1T_2\lVert \leq \lVert T_1\lVert\lVert T_2\lVert,~~~~~~~~~(**)$$ since $\lVert T_1T_2(x) \lVert_Z \leq \lVert T_1 \lVert\lVert T_2x \lVert_Y \leq \lVert T_1 \lVert\lVert T_2 \lVert\lVert x \lVert_X$ for the linear maps $T_1:(Y,\lVert \cdot \lVert_Y) \to (Z,\lVert \cdot \lVert_Z)$ and $T_2:(X,\lVert \cdot \lVert_X) \to (Y,\lVert \cdot \lVert_Y)$ with $T_2(X)=Y$.

My confusion:

However, the definition of operator norm itself imply the inequality $(**)$, what would be the need for such a sub-multiplicative condition $(*)$? Any conceptual mislead here?

Comment: You can introduce matrix norms that are not induced by norms in the underlying vector spaces, so your derivation merely means that any norm induced by a vector space one is a norm in the sense of the general definition, which is great to know but which doesn't exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: But the matrix norm itself a norm on the space of matrices, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So, what is your conclusion, Sorry to say I am not getting your comment completely.

Comment: It is that the general axiomatic definition allows for a wider class of norms on the matrix algebra than just "operator norms" $\|A\|=\sup\{|Ax|:|x|\le 1\}$ and that the sub-multiplicativity condition is there just to enable one to write the natural inequalities even if the norm on the matrix algebra has nothing to do with how it acts on the underlying space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got my mislead here. I have taken the operator norm as the only matrix norm, right? Can we show some other matrix norms like Frobenius, Maximum row/column sum,...violating the inequalities ensured by operator norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that the definition you are given is that of a normed  algebra, and the two ingredients are not clearly separated.

In principle, a norm does not have to satisfy such condition. Actually, a norm only requires an underlying vector space structure and the usual axioms of norm.

If your space has an additional multiplication operation, then it makes sense to require its continuity with respect to the factors. This is what you call a normed algebra.

In the space of matrices you have both a vector space structure and a multiplication, so it makes sense to require the extra continuity property. But in principle you can have norms not satisfying that property.

It turns out that if you consider the operator norm, the extra condition is automatically satisfied.

I am not aware that any norm in the space of matrices corresponds to an operator norm for some underlying norm in the vector space. If that is the case, the extra requirement would be redundant of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot...